# SQOOP Mysql import to Hive error User does not belong to hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

when i used this command to import table into Hive

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.200.33:3306/db_socmed_gp \
--username=fanta \
--password=fanta \
--table=tb_gp_account \
--hive-import \
--hive-database=db_socmed_gp \
--target-dir=home/fanta/db_socmed_gp2 \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--direct
```

I got the error when sqoop importing data to Hive :

```
Loading data to table db_socmed_gp.tb_gp_account
chgrp: changing ownership of 'hdfs://lobah:8021/user/hive/warehouse/db_socmed_gp.db/tb_gp_account/part-m-00000': User does not belong to hive
chgrp: changing ownership of 'hdfs://lobah:8021/user/hive/warehouse/db_socmed_gp.db/tb_gp_account/part-m-00001': User does not belong to hive
chgrp: changing ownership of 'hdfs://lobah:8021/user/hive/warehouse/db_socmed_gp.db/tb_gp_account/part-m-00002': User does not belong to hive
chgrp: changing ownership of 'hdfs://lobah:8021/user/hive/warehouse/db_socmed_gp.db/tb_gp_account/part-m-00003': User does not belong to hive
Table db_socmed_gp.tb_gp_account stats: [numFiles=4, totalSize=21254586]
```

Comment: Are you using HDP or Cloudera? If you execute `groups` in the command line (with the same user running the Sqoop command), what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

The user You are trying  not part of the hadoop/Hive group to modify the content of the warehouse directory. Give the necessary permissions to the user group and try again.

Answer (score 0):

i also met this problem 
you should change the derby to mysql 
then try it..